# Strange "Two-way binding" error inside style trigger

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have simple code:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsValidated" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

And this causes exception

**Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.**

And IsValidated declaration:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsValidatedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsValidated", typeof(bool), typeof(MyTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, IsValidatedPropertyChanged));
```

I cannot change declaration because this in external assembly.

Why i have this message and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the error is inside the style trigger. You probably bind to IsValidated somewhere else in your code like this

```
{Binding}
```

or

```
<Binding />
```

but a two way binding needs a [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) even if the binding is equivalent (the period binds to the current source).

```
{Binding Path=.}
```

respectively

```
<Binding Path="." />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the two-way binding on this dependency property, remove the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` option. If you do, try using a `DataTrigger` with a binding to RelativeSource Self instead of the `Trigger`.